# list linux partition names only in bash

Tags: linux, bash, df

df on linux lists the following stats on partitions.

```
-bash-4.1# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3            1918217320 1473337340 347440136  81% /
tmpfs                 32970328         0  32970328   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1               482214    148534    308781  33% /boot
/dev/sdd1            1922860884 1638599284 186585876  90% /disk5
/dev/sdc1            1922858352 1474925416 350257336  81% /disk2
/dev/sdb1            1922858352 1028783752 796399000  57% /disk4
```

If I want to get a list of the partition names, for example:
"/dev/sda3 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdc1..."
how do I do it in bash?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the information you receive from `df`? Can you describe the end goal?

Comment: Amongst other utilities awk and grep are your friends.

Comment: df | awk '{print $1}'

Answer (score 9):

To list all partitions defined for a device as root run:

> lsblk

OR

> fdisk -l

OR

> cat /proc/partitions

And also as mentioned by @Giedrius Rekasius

> fdisk -l /dev/sda | grep '^/dev' | cut -d' ' -f1

Answer (score 5):

`df` will display only mounted partitions. If that's what you want then to extract the device nodes from `df` output you `grep` for the lines starting with "/dev" and `cut` the first column out of the remaining output:

```
df | grep '^/dev' | cut -d' ' -f1
```

or to list them on a single line separated by spaces:

```
df | grep '^/dev' | cut -d' ' -f1 | tr '\n' ' '
```

If you want to get a list of partitions which are not necessarily mounted then as root you can run `fdisk -l` and optionally specify device(s) to scan for partitions:

```
fdisk -l [device...]
```

If you don't specify any device then fdisk will use devices mentioned in `/proc/partitions` if that file exists.

Fdisk will output information in a similar format as `df` so to extract device nodes you can do the same thing as described for `df`:

```
fdisk -l | grep '^/dev' | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Answer (score 3):

`blkid` displays just real storages attached to computer with or without mounted.

```
# sudo blkid | awk '{print substr($1, 0, length($1) - 1)}'

/dev/sda1
/dev/sda2
/dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb2
/dev/sr1
```

Answer (score 2):

Some ideas...

`awk '{print $1}' /proc/mounts`

`df | awk '{print $1}'`

`df | cut -f1 -d " "`

Comment: fdisk -l | awk '/\/dev\/s[a-z]/ {print "Partition" " " $1}'

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
df | cut -d" " -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
df --type ext2 --type ext3 --type ext4 | tail -n +2 | awk '{ print $1 }' | tr '\n' ' '
```

- `--type <filesystem>` allows you to specify which filesystems you are interested in
- `tail -n +2` starts printing from the second row of output (so that the heading line isn't printed)
- `awk '{ print $1 }'` will print the leftmost column which contains the partition information
- `tr '\n' ' '` will translate newlines to spaces, so that the information is all on one line

Answer (score 1):

```
  [root@ct01 ~]# ls /dev/sd*[0-9]
  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2
```

Answer (score 0):

This command will list all of the partitions on the system in a form that's easy to iterate on:

```
tail -n +3 /proc/partitions | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

Comment: Should be `tail -n+3` and it will list not only partitions but also devices, e.g. `sda`.